# How can I get rid of margin around my HTML content?

Tags: html

The following HTML display fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;">
            <div>Hello</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, there is a space of around 10 pixel between the left and top edges my div and the browser window.
Is there a way to get rid of it so that the div is "glued" to the browser window?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could add CSS to the document....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { margin:0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;">
        <div>Hello</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or you could add the CSS as an inline style

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;">
        <div>Hello</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All browsers have a default margin around the top and left edge of the window. There's nothing wrong with your page. You merely need to tell the browser to remove the default margins.

Answer (score 6):

To leave the padding and margins of other elements alone, just reset the body.

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding style to the `body` tag, like this:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>     <head>
>         <title>Hello</title>
>     </head>
>     <body style="margin: 0;">
>         <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;">
>             <div>Hello</div>
>         </div>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS reset.

```
<style type="text/css">* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check out freeCodeCamp they use the following code to accomplish this.

I did this exact thing to remove the left and top default margins on the HTML:

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

To prove this worked I placed a 1px solid border around the body element. Once I implemented the above rule the body then filled the entire page with no padding or margin. This is called normalizing the CSS rules.

Answer (score -1):

If you do any of the above codes, but you do not set your table properties to percent rather than pixels, you will probably still end up with a margin-type space around your page. Like as in the bottom scroll bar will still show.

```
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td width="15%" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#B8B8B6">
</td>
<td width="85%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left" valign="top">
</td>
</table>
```