# How to get rid of "margin"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to get rid of the white space at the very bottom of my webpage, it is really annoying me and it isn't meant to be there.

**Code below:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="freeloves.css">
```

**HTML Code :**

```
  <body>      
  <div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logo.png" class="logo" alt="The Free Loves" width="544" height="100" /></li>
    <li><a href="test.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2103.html">Album <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2441.html">Album Featured</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item2"><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2103.html">No Space<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2377.html">Album 1 Column, No Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2356.html">Album 2 Columns, No Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2103.html">Album 3 Columns, No Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2357.html">Album 4 Columns, No Space</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li> 
    <li class="submenu-item62"><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2360.html">With Space <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2378.html">Album 1 Column With Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2361.html">Album 2 Columns With Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2360.html">Album 3 Columns With Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2362.html">Album 4 Columns With Space</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-3251" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-album menu-item-3251"><a href="test/album/hundred-miles/index.html">Inside Album</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2211.html">Event <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2079.html">Event List</a></li>
      <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2211.html">Event List With Month</a></li>
      <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2434.html">Event Widget Style</a></li>
      <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2101.html">Single Event</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2446.html">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pages <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://themes.goodlayers2.com/musicclub/404error">404 Page</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item50"><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1424.html">Features <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1424.html">New Page Builder</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1482.html">Parallax/Color Wrapper</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1476.html">Custom Skin</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1493.html">Sidebar Size Customizable</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=1566">Scalable Container</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1572.html">Floating Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1569.html">Boxed/Full Style</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1575.html">Woocommerce Friendly</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1496.html">Mega Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1513.html">Unlimited Sidebar</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1510.html">Font Uploader</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li> 
      <li  class="submenu-item51"><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1321.html">Shop<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1231.html">Shop With Sidebar</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1321.html">Shop Full Width</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1232.html">Cart</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1233.html">Checkout</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1234.html">My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1629.html">Contact Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1631.html">Contact Page 2</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item52"><a href="test.html#">Video Tutorial<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1746.html">Installing theme and Setting as demo site</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1762.html">Page Builder</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1748.html">Creating Portfolio &#038; Filterer</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1750.html">Creating Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1754.html">Thumbnail Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1752.html">Creating Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu-item53"><a href="test.html#">Gallery<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul class="dl-submenu">
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1598.html">Gallery 2 Columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1602.html">Gallery 3 Columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1605.html">Gallery 4 Columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1620.html">Gallery 5 Columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2419.html">Gallery 2 Columns With Caption</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2420.html">Gallery 3 Columns With Caption</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2421.html">Gallery 4 Columns With Caption</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2422.html">Gallery 5 Columns With Caption</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=84.html">Testimonial</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2171">Portfolio<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow"></a>
<ul>
  <li class="submenu-item54"><a href="test.html#">Portfolio With Text<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/portfolio-1-column-with-text-and-space/page/1/index.html">Portfolio 1 Column With Text And Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=906">Portfolio 2 Columns With Text And Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=100">Portfolio 3 Columns With Text And Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=908">Portfolio 4 Columns With Text And Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2147">Portfolio 2 Columns With Text, No Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2146">Portfolio 3 Columns With Text, No Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2148">Portfolio 4 Columns With Text, No Space</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li class="submenu-item70"><a href="test.html#">Portfolio Modern<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/portfolio-1-column-modern-with-space/page/1/index.html">Portfolio 1 Column Modern Style With Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/portfolio-2-columns-modern-with-space/page/1/index.html">Portfolio 2 Columns Modern Style With Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2161">Portfolio 3 Columns Modern Style With Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2162">Portfolio 4 Columns Modern Style With Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/portfolio-2-columns-modern-style-no-space/page/1/index.html">Portfolio 2 Columns Modern Style, No Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2171">Portfolio 3 Columns Modern Style, No Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=2170">Portfolio 4 Columns Modern Style, No Space</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
    <li class="submenu-item71"><a href="test.html#">Portfolio With Filter<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=954">Portfolio Grid 1 Columns With Filter</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=952">Portfolio Grid 2 Columns With Filter</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=949">Portfolio Grid 3 Columns With Filter</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=947">Portfolio Grid 4 Columns With Filter</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="test/blog-full-with-right-sidebar/page/1/index.html">Blog<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow3"></a>
<ul>
  <li class="submenu-item72"><a href="test.html#">Blog Full<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/blog-full-with-right-sidebar/page/1/index.html">Blog Full With Right Sidebar</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/blog-full-with-left-sidebar/page/1/index.html">Blog Full With Left Sidebar</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/blog-full-with-both-sidebar/page/1/index.html">Blog Full With Both Sidebar</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/blog-full-without-sidebar/page/1/index.html">Blog Full Without Sidebar</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li class="submenu-item73" data-column="three columns" data-size="1/4"><a href="test.html#">Blog Column<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/blog-1-column/page/1/index.html">Blog 1 Column (Right Sidebar)</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/blog-2-columns/page/1/index.html">Blog 2 Columns (Right Sidebar)</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=878.html">Blog 3 Columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/blog-4-columns/page/1/index.html">Blog 4 Columns</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li class="submenu-item74"><a href="test.html#">Blog Masonry<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=887.html">Blog 2 Columns &#8211; Masonry (Right Sidebar)</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=888.html">Blog 3 Columns &#8211; Masonry</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=889.html">Blog 4 Columns &#8211; Masonry</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li class="submenu-item55"><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2063.html">Blog Medium<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2065.html">Blog Medium With Left Sidebar</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2063.html">Blog Medium With Right Sidebar</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2067.html">Blog Medium With Both Sidebar</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/blog-medium-without-sidebar/page/1/index.html">Blog Medium Without Sidebar</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=120.html">Shortcodes <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow4"></a>
<ul>
  <li class="submenu-item61 menu-code"><a href="test.html#">Set 1<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=149.html">Accordion/Toggle Box</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=784.html">Audio Shortcode</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=156.html">Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1017.html">Column Shortcode</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=203.html">Divider</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2541.html">Event Widget</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=705.html">Gallery Shortcode</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li class="submenu-item60 menu-code"><a href="test.html#">Set 2<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=296.html">Heading Tag</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=653.html">icons &#038; icon boxes</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=211.html">Lightbox &#038; Frames</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=236.html">Notification Boxes</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=456.html">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=2525.html">Music Player</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=1039">Post Slider</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="submenu-item80"><a href="test.html#">Set 3<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=1400">Price Table</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=1084">Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.thefreeloves.com/test/?page_id=258">Progress Circle</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=245.html">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=1045.html">Slider Shortcode</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=640.html">Space</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
    <li class="submenu-item81"><a href="test.html#">Set 4<img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow2"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=116.html">Styled Box</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=285.html">Stunning Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=687.html">Table</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=218.html">Tabs</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=428.html">Testimonial &#038; Quote</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=120.html">Typography</a></li>
    <li><a href="test/index.html%3Fp=797.html">Video</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div id="toggle-left" class="toggles"><i><img src="arrow-right.png" alt="left arrow" class="toggle-arrow" id="left-arrow"></i></div>
    <div id="toggle-right" class="toggles"><i><img src="arrow-right.png" alt="right arrow" class="toggle-arrow"></i></div>
    <ul class="slides">
    <li class="li"><img class="slide" src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA8373.jpg" alt="Free Loves"></li>
    <li class="li"><img class="slide" src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA8847.jpg" alt="Free Loves"></li>
    <li class="li"><img class="slide" src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HD-Musical-Instruments-Guitar-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="Free Loves"></li>
    <li class="li"><img class="slide" src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA8607.jpg" alt="Free Loves"></li>
    <li class="li"><img class="slide" src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA8373.jpg" alt="Free Loves"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="music">
<!--<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/61481425&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>-->
</div>
<div class="content1">
<h3 class="text1">Our Latest Album<span class="slash">   /   </span><span class="text2">Fresh from the house of Music Club Band</span></h3>
</div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav ul li").children("ul").hide(); //hides the lists when documents loads


    $(".nav ul li").hover( 
        function(){//onmouseover 
            $(this).children("ul").delay(450).slideDown(200); 
        }, 
        function(){//onmouseout 
            $(this).children("ul").slideUp(200); 
    }); 

    //cache DOM
    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.li');
    var $slideImg = $slides.find('img');
    var $toggleLeft = $('#toggle-left');
    var $toggleRight = $('#toggle-right');
    var $pauseBtn = $('#pause-btn');
    var $playBtn = $('#play-btn');

    //configuration
    var width = $slider.width();
    var animationSpeed = 1500;
    var pause = 9000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var interval;

    $slideContainer.css('width', width * $slides.length);
    $slideImg.css('width', width);

    $pauseBtn.click(function(){stopSlider();$pauseBtn.toggle();$playBtn.toggle();});
    $playBtn.click(function(){startSlider();$playBtn.toggle();$pauseBtn.toggle();});
    $toggleLeft.click(function(){
        stopSlider();
        if (currentSlide === 1) {
            currentSlide = $slides.length;
            $slideContainer.css({'margin-left': '-'+width*($slides.length-1)+'px'});
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
                currentSlide--;
            });
        } else {
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){
                currentSlide--;
            });
        }
        startSlider();
    });
    $toggleRight.click(function(){
        stopSlider();
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){
            currentSlide++;
            if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
        startSlider();
    });
    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){
                currentSlide++;
                if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    }

    function stopSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    startSlider();
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
```

**CSS :**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-wrapper {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
text-align: left;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgba(34,34,34,0.5);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav ul li a,visited {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav ul li img.arrow {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 17%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li img.arrow3 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 24%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li:hover img.arrow3 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 24%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li:hover img.arrow4 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 12%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li img.arrow4 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 12%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li ul li:hover img.arrow2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 7%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li ul li img.arrow2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 7%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li:hover img.arrow {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 17%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222;
  border: 5px solid #222;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
}


.nav ul ul li a,visited {
  color: #ccc;
}

.nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav ul li ul li.submenu-item52 ul {
  min-width: 350px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item2 ul {
  left: 147px;
  top: 50px;
  min-width: 250px;
} 

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item50 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item62 ul {
  left: 147px;
  top: 100px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item51 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 100px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item52 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 252px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item53 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 303px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item54 ul {
  left: 190px;
  top: -1px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item55 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 151px;
  min-width: 345px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item60 ul {
  left: 152px;
  top: 50px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item61 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: -1px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item70 ul {
  left: 189px;
  top: 50px;
  min-width: 350px;
} 

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item71 ul {
  left: 189px;
  top: 100px;
  min-width: 350px;
} 

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item72 ul {
  left: 140px;
  top: -1px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item73 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  min-width: 345px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item74 ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 100px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item80 ul {
  left: 153px;
  top: 100px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.nav ul ul li.submenu-item81 ul {
  left: 153px;
  top: 151px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.menu-code {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.menu-code ul li {
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.logo {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.nav ul li ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #D4941F;
}

ul li ul li { 
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

ul li ul {
  border-right: 5px solid #111;
}

.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.slides, .slide {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slides img {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 971px;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1); 
    filter: brightness(1);
}
.slide {
    float: left;
}
.slider .toggles {
    color: #000;
    height: 48px;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    width: 48px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.slider .toggles:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider:hover .toggles {
    opacity: 1;
}
.slider .toggles i:before {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.slider #toggle-right i:before, #slider #toggle-left i:before {
    height: 20px;
    width: 18px;
}

#toggle-right {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
#toggle-left {
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 75px;
}

#left-arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.toggle-arrow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 180px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.music {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 800px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.music:hover {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 800px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.content1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/album-title.jpg");
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.text1 {
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", Optima, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #6CB9D9;
}

.slash {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: better create a demo?

Comment: I created plunkr for OP. Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/I2V0PoUri5o8tzjzeDHt?p=preview

Comment: Hey. I couldn't really see the margin you're referring to!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `<whitespaceattheverybottomofmywebpage />` tag? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo OHHHHHH. That would be it, thanks!

Comment: AMorris, I transferred your pastebin directly into this page since it's usually better to have it self-contained. However, there appears to be some naked CSS at the end of your HTML. What was your intent there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space is because of that code:

```
<div class="content1">
<h3 class="text1">Our Latest Album<span class="slash">   /   </span><span class="text2">Fresh from the house of Music Club Band</span></h3>
</div>
```

If you remove that, the whitespace is gone.

---

But if you like it, you can solve by adding `margin-bottom: 0` and `margin-top: 0` to the `h3.text1`:

```
.text1 {
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", Optima, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[So beautiful](http://embed.plnkr.co/aQh3GOYL8F07Vn6HeKDh/preview)!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this stems from the default margin/padding of body. Try adding

```
html,body {padding:0; margin:0;}
```

[Refer This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458383/how-can-i-get-rid-of-margin-around-my-html-content)